# How to launch two applications without desktop environment

Tags: linux, debian, x11

I would like to launch a GTK applicaton and a Chromium window, each fullscreen on its own monitor, without having to login and start desktop environments.
How would I do that?

I ran `systemctl disable lightdm.service` and created two systemd services to launch each respective application, but now it boots into command-line mode instead of showing the applications.

Comment: Would you consider using a Wayland window composer, such as [Sway](https://github.com/swaywm/sway), which has multi-monitor support? Both GTK and Chromium have native Wayland support. Unless you have an antique nvidia GPU, this setup should work.

Comment: @memchr Wayland does not have multi-monitor touchscreen calibration support, so I must use the X server.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of disabling LightDM, perhaps consider [configuring its autologin](https://www.enricozini.org/blog/2019/himblick/x-autologin/) to start X11 with appropriate users, each with a `.xsession` that runs the required application.  Then you won't get a desktop environment.

It might also be possible to run a single X server spanning both monitors; I assume you're able to choose your approach and set it up appropriately.

Answer (score 1):

Chromium, by design, **will refuse to work as root**. (And that is a **very** good thing.)

So, you need a user session, no matter whether you want it. That solves the issue of having to launch something without a desktop environment – you'll really want one.

Nothing, however, says that a desktop environment needs to be as large and complex as say Gnome or KDE. I personally use awesome and just not have a menu bar in the rc.lua. Other people prefer i3. Or sommermiefWM or any other light desktop environment that's able to put windows on the screen you want them to go.

Comment: You don't need a _desktop_ environment - just a simple display manager such as `nodm` (or perhaps one for each display).  That's enough to start a single X11 application as a specified user.

Comment: Some example config for this that I made for a simple photo frame: https://gitlab.com/murukesh/dp (uses autologin in getty to start a shell and then the shell starts X11, which starts i3, which launches `feh` and conky)

Comment: Previously used lightdm+openbox / enabled autologin in lightdm for this.